# How to check whether an element is in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I want to check if zero is in this list of lists. For example:

`lst = [[2,2,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]`

If lists in 'lst' contains "0", then `print("Yes")`, else `print("No")`. The above list should give the result of "Yes", since `lst[1][2] == 0`.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
if (0 in (lst[x] for x in range(len(lst)))):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: print ("Yes" if any(0 in x for x in lst) else "No")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `range(len)`, you can directly iterate over sublists:

```
for sublist in lst:
    if 0 in sublist:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

With given input, output:

```
No
Yes
No
No
```